# Need help regarding String Derangements using Inclusion/Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I have this question that states:

Using Inclusion/exclusion, find the number of derangements of each of the following strings.

A) aabcd

B) aabbcc

I understand inclusion/exclusion I just don't understand how it applies to this type of question.

I would appreciate the help and some clarification on how to go about solving these types of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to understand what a derangement is. Suppose we want to count all the derangements of the set {${1,2,3,4,5}$}. That is, we want to count all the permutations for which **all** the numbers in the set are in an 'incorrect' position.

For instance, suppose we assign $1$ to the first place, $2$ to the second place, $3$ in third, etc. as above, let's call these the natural positions of the set.

Then, {$3,5,2,1,4$} is a derangement where **all** numbers are not in the "correct" or "natural" position.

What does this have to do with inclusion-exclusion?

Let $A_i$ be an element denoted by the $i$th position being in it's natural position, namely $i$. Then we seek to count all possibilities where no $A_i$ is in its right position. Hence, we want to count:

$|\overline{A_1} \cap \overline{A_2} \cap ... \cap \overline{A_n}|$

But this equals:

$|\overline{A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n} | = |A|-|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n|$

Where $|A|$ is the number of all permutations of regarding $A_1$,$A_2$,...$A_n$.

Then, as you are familiar with inclusion exclusion principle, this term $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n|$ you know how to expand.

This should be enough to get you started. Be mindful when counting since some of your strings have repeating characters.

Comment: I am doing the exact same problem, and although I understand how to find the derangements of sets like $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ I am completely stuck on the duplicated terms. Can you help @Areyouheaty?

Comment: @Nixie777 A hint: consider the string $aabcd$ as the question asked. Since $a$ has a duplicate, temporarily give both different subscript labels to distinguish them. Now count the derangements with the string $a_1 a_2 b c d$. To solve the original problem, realize that $a_1$ and $a_2$ swapped count as the same string, so seek to correct overcounting where it happened.