# Use inclusion/exclusion to find the number of derangements of each of the following strings.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

a) aabcd (already answered)

b) aabbcc

There is a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1486837) exactly like the one I asked, however I am still stuck and still need help. Here is my attempt

> Let A denotes where aa occurs, B denotes where bb occurs, C denotes where cc occurs, and |U|=$\frac{6!}{2^3}$. Then $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-(|AB|+|AC|+|BC|)+|ABC|$.
>
> > For |A|+|B|+|C| glue aa together for |A|, bb for |B| and cc for |C|
> >
> > > |A|: $\frac{5!}{2^2}$ |B|: $\frac{5!}{2^2}$  |C|: $\frac{5!}{2^2}$ $\implies$ |A|+|B|+|C|=$3\left(\frac{5!}{2^2}\right)$
> >
> > For |AB|+|AC|+|BC|=$3\left(\frac{4!}{2}\right)$
> >
> > For |ABC|= 3!
>
> So |U|-$|A\cup B\cup C| = \frac{6!}{2^3}-\left[\frac{5!}{2^2}-3\left(\frac{4!}{2}\right)+3!\right] = 30$

Now thanks to the people who already answered this we know that the actual answer is 10.

As you all can see I am doing something wrong, but I not sure what. By using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle please help me figure out how I need to get the correct answer.

Comment: Do you happen to know the final answers?

Comment: @iamwhoiam I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work out the first example (we'll use common letters for convenience):

$aabcd$

First letter $a$ needs to go to position $3,4$ or $5$ so $3$ choices

Second letter $a$ now should have the same $3$ choices but the first letter $a$ already took a spot, so $2$ choices.

Those first two $a$'s don't generate $3*2$ combinations but only $3$, of the form $\cdot \cdot aa\cdot ,\cdot\cdot a\cdot a,\cdot\cdot\cdot aa$

Now for the last three letters we can work them all in one pack : if the first two $a$ didn't take their place, then they have only $2$ choices, if not, they have $3$ choices. There can only be one of the three initial letters $cde$ so that none of the two $a$ moved to their spot, so one letter out of $cde$ has $2$ choices, and the two left have each $3$ choices. Thanks to Platty you also need to take into consideration that each time you place one of those three letters you take away a spot for the remaining letters so they generate $2*2*1$ combinations.

So finally we got the number of possible derrangement : $3*2*2*1=12$

For the second string $aabbcc$ the number of derangement is $10$.

Comment: Once you place letters, you decrease the number of choices for the remainder - in particular, the last letter should only have one choice.

Comment: That's very correct !

Comment: @platty I edited my answer, thanks for this I completly missed it the first time =)

Comment: I think it should be $3 \times 2 \times 2 \times 1$. You have 2 choices for the letter in the last 3 not replaced by an $a$, then 2 choices for the one it replaces, and 1 for the last one.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry I miss type, the answer is 12 and it's indeed $3*2*2*1$

Comment: @iamwhoiam wouldn't the final answer then be 12?

Comment: @platty Yep, sorry, my bad

Comment: @platty thanks man you're saving the day !

Comment: @Furrane do you think you can also try the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle and get the same answers. I've tried in notebook and my answers are completely off?

Answer (score 2):

I'll help you with the first one. The second is similar.To make stuff easier, I'll write the string as $\alpha_1\alpha_2\beta\gamma\delta$.

Note that the number of derangements for the string is $D_5$. However, in ${\frac{1}{4}}^{th}$ of those we have $\alpha_1$ in the second position. The same holds true when $\alpha_2$ is in the first position. We thus get, 
$D_5 - \frac{2}{4}D_5$. We have however, over-subtracted the case when $\alpha_2$ is in the first position and $\alpha_1$ is in the first. This happens in ${\frac{D_3}{D_5}}^{th}$ of the cases (Fix the positions for the first two letters; the rest can be deranged in $D_3$ ways).

The final answer is thus, $$D_5 - \frac{2}{4}D_5 + \frac{D_3}{D_5}D_5$$

Since the two $\alpha$s are indistinguishable, the final answer is $\frac{24}{2} = 12$

Comment: I'm still confused. I can't really visualize $\frac{2}{5}D_{5}-\frac{1}{10}D_{5}$.

Comment: @Nixie777 I've edited the answer. Does that help?

Comment: You also need to account for the fact that the two $\alpha$s are indistinguishable in the final string - once you do, both answers will match. :)

Comment: Indeed platty is right again, you're counting combinations twice.

Comment: So since, we over counted by two, we divide 24 by 2 to get 12.